# Displaying timeseries json data in table format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have the following json data which i would like to display in format of a HTML table.

Data:

```
data = [{"target": "cpu1", "datapoints": [[100, 1388661130], [100, 1388661140], [100, 1388661150], [100, 1388661160], [100, 1388661170], [100, 1388661180], [100, 1388661190], [100, 1388661200], [100, 1388661210], [100, 1388661220], [100, 1388661230], [100, 1388661240], [100, 1388661250]]}, {"target": "cpu2", "datapoints": [[400, 1388661130], [400, 1388661140], [400, 1388661150], [400, 1388661160], [400, 1388661170], [400, 1388661180], [400, 1388661190], [400, 1388661200], [400, 1388661210], [400, 1388661220], [400, 1388661230], [400, 1388661240], [400, 1388661250]]},  {"target": "cpu3", "datapoints": [[400, 1388661130], [400, 1388661140], [400, 1388661150], [400, 1388661160], [400, 1388661170], [400, 1388661180], [400, 1388661190], [400, 1388661200], [400, 1388661210], [400, 1388661220], [400, 1388661230], [400, 1388661240], [400, 1388661250]]}];
```

My idea is to display it as a table:

```
Time|Cpu 1 | cpu 2| cpu 3|
t1    v1     v2      v3
```

My code so far is in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arg9X/55/), where i succeeded in geting the table format except that my cpu2 and cpu 3 are not populated:

```
   Time|cpu1|cpu2|cpu3
    t1   v1
    t2   v2
    t1   v3
    t2   v4
    t1   v5
    t2   v6
```

My code is available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/arg9X/55/).

Any help would be welcome, Currently I am using html tables, is there another method using jquery table plugins to simplify the task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the update fiddle @ [here](http://jsfiddle.net/arg9X/58/)

```
           if(data){
            var len = data.length;
            var row = new Array;
          // alert (len);
            var txt = "";
            if(len > 0){
                var tab2 = document.getElementById("table");
                var table = document.getElementById("coltab");
                 for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
                    //alert (i);
                   // var row = tab2.insertRow(1);
                    var len_data = data[i].datapoints.length;

                    var cell1 = table.insertCell(i+1);
                    //var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                     cell1.innerHTML = data[i].target;
                     for (var j = 0; j <len_data;j++) {
                         if (i==0)
                         row[j] = tab2.insertRow(j+1);
                         if (i==0)
                         {
                         var cell2 = row[j].insertCell(0);
                         cell2.innerHTML = data[i].datapoints[j][1];
                         }
                         var cell3 = row[j].insertCell(-1); 
                         cell3.innerHTML = data[i].datapoints[j][0];  
                     }
                }
            }
        }
```

The purpose of argument in `insertCell` is like this

> Required in Firefox and Opera, optional in IE, Chrome and Safari. A
>   number (starts at 0) that specifies the position of the new cell in
>   the current row. The value of 0 results in that the new cell will be
>   inserted at the first position. The value of -1 can also be used;
>   which results in that the new cell will be inserted at the last
>   position.
>
> If this parameter is omitted, insertCell() inserts the new cell at the
>   last position in IE and at the first position in Chrome and Safari.

Also by calling `insertRow` every time you are over writing the existing row every time in table. it have to be called only once

Comment: The solution is not generic, as you assume that we have only 3 targets, correct me if am wrong. How can this scale up?

Comment: var cell3 = row[j].insertCell(-1); // assumes we have knowledge of data elements.
  cell3.innerHTML = data[i].datapoints[j][0];

Comment: No solution is generic. var cell3 = row[j].insertCell(-1);  will add newly cell at the end of the row. ie further cpus @ right side. You can check with less or more number targets amd give me example. if its not working. i will check it

Comment: clean, thanks. Instead of generating data using html, do we have any plugins?

Answer (score 1):

Write:

```
if (data) {
    var len = data.length;
    var txt = "",
        th = "";
    if (len > 0) {
        var alen = data[0].datapoints.length;
        for (var j = 0; j < alen; j++) {
            txt += "<tr>";//new row
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                var dt = data[i].datapoints[j][0];
                var first = data[i].datapoints[j][1];
                if (i == j) {
                    th += "<th>" + data[i].target + "</th>";
                }
                if (i == 0) {
                    txt += "<td>" + first + "</td>"; //first cell in each row
                }
                txt += "<td>" + dt + "</td>";
            }
            txt += "</tr>";//end row
        }
    }
    $("#table").append(txt); //table data
    $("#coltab").append(th); //header row
}
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/arg9X/62/)

Comment: How do we change the colors using this approach? say we want to compare to a threshold (say 80), above 80, green, below 80 is red

Comment: precisely, but may i ask, why are you trying to generate the html? Does this have merits over insert cell or cell.backgroundcolor etc.

Comment: Also, in jquery do we have any plugins which directly tabulate data instead of using HTML

Comment: @VamsiKrishna I am not much comfortable with javascirpt so I wrote code this way.

Comment: Hi, If we have a URL which gives me json data. Do we need to send ajax requests? I am using Giraffe.https://github.com/kenhub/giraffe/blob/master/js/giraffe.js. generate URL function